# Origin of "facial" as a noun

Tags: etymology

> I got a facial at the beauty salon.

Any dictionary I've checked confirms that *facial* can be a noun. For example, my *Shorter Oxford* calls it "A beauty treatment for the face" and dates it to the early 20th century.

What is the origin of *facial* as a noun? Did it come from a phrase in which it appeared as an adjective? Did something like "She got a facial *treatment* at the beauty salon" simply evolve to drop the noun?

If so, what *was* the original phrase? And when did the adjective become the noun? Who dropped the (other) noun - was it the professionals who provided the "facial treatments" (or "facial whatevers")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Etymonline suggests](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=facial) that the noun form was first noted in 1914:

> c.1600, "face to face," from Fr. facial, from M.L. facialis "of the face," from facies (see face (n.)). Meaning "of the face" is from 1818. **The noun meaning "beauty treatment for the face" is from 1914, American English.**

While it's difficult to pinpoint the exact phrase that it abbreviates, looking at probable candidates such as *facial treatment*, *facial pack*, *facial cleaning*, *facial cleansing*, and *facial massage*, suggests that *facial massage* was the most likely. The following instances all antedate the 1914 suggested in etymonline:

From *Beauty, Its Attainment and Preservation* (1892):

> Aside from its physically remedial effects, it has also been recently adopted as a beautifier, and **facial massage is one of the expedients now resorted to by the fashionable woman** in her endeavor to circumvent old Time by as far as possible ...

From *The Art of Massage: A Practical Manual for the Student, the Nurse and the Practitioner* by John Harvey Kellogg<sup>1</sup> (1895):

> Massage for Wrinkles — **Facial massage** may be made useful in removing wrinkles.

I have no idea *who* decided to abbreviate *facial massage* to *facial*. But the probability of it having been those involved in the industry is high.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Yes, the [very same one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Harvey_Kellogg)</sub>